# Infinite Union of Open Sets is Closed Set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am trying rewrite the set:
$$E_1 = (0,1] $$
as a collection of countable unions or intersections. I understand there are a ton of ways to do this, however, I just want to make sure mine is correct so I understand how to evaluate these objects. My thought was to break this into:
$$E_1=(0,1)\cup[1]=\bigcup\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}[-\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}] \cup\bigcap\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}) $$
I believe the infinite union should be equal to $(0,1)$ and the infinite intersection should be equal to $[1]$ so that their union is simply $E_1$. Is this correct?

EDIT: This was supposed to read:
$$E_1=(0,1)\cup[1]=\bigcup\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}] \cup\bigcap\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}) $$

Comment: Adding on to Paulo's answer, here are a few ideas for you to try to get $(0, 1)$ (a) create intervals which "grow" to the right i.e. they are all of the form $(0, x_n)$ for each $n$, (b) create intervals which "grow" out from 0.5 i.e. they are all of the form $(0.5-y_n, 0.5+z_n)$ for each $n$. There are other approaches as well, of course, but these are the two that I think are easiest to "see".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of sets $\{I_n\}$ where $ I_n = [-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]$ is decreasing, and $I_{n} \subset I_2$ (for all $n$), so its  union is just $I_2$. You wont get $E_1$ like this. You are right the intersection is 1. You can write $E_1$ directly as intersection (enumerable) of open sets.

While the infinite union of open sets can be closed (i.e $ \bigcup (-n,n) = \mathbb{R}$), it is necessarily open as well, so you cannot write $E_1$ as infinite union of open sets, because $E_1$ is not open.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped defining the infinite union. As I had it written in my notebook, it was supposed to be $[\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}]$. Would that then be correct?

Comment: Now it looks fine. You should try to show inclusions directly as well, i know its a bit boring, but it always works. Take a $x$ in $E_1$ and show its on the right hand side, and similarly for a $y$ on the right handed side, show its on $E_1$. If you are doing analysis 1, your teacher will likely want to see you do it on the tests as well.  Thats one of the reasons it would be easier to represent $E_1$ as intersection, this verification becomes easier.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will definitely keep that in mind!